# Linq date comparison does not work like in sql server management studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

I'm trying to get the data from a table with the dates of a specific timeframe. In this case my timeframe is a month. When I try to get the data for the month with linq I get 111 entries but when i do the query in the sql server management studio I get 112.

The dates of the entries are:

```
- 2013-08-31 18:00:00.0000000 +07:00
- 2013-08-31 21:00:00.0000000 +03:00
- 2013-08-31 23:00:00.0000000 +01:00
```

The last one is filtered out with linq when i try to get the entries between the first of August at 00:00:00 and the last of August at 23:59:59.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
var startDate = new DateTime('01.08.2013');
var endDate = new DateTime('01.09.2013').AddMiliseconds(-1);
var count = dbContext.table.Where(d => d.Date >= startDate && d.Date <= endDate).Count();
```

Any clues why in linq the last entry is filtered out while a direct sql execution shows that entry?

Comment: What are the datatypes for the field in the database, and what SQL statement are you using? Looks like an inconsistency between your SQL and Linq statement when it comes to time zone handling.

Comment: Did you try checking what SQL statement is generated as a result of LINQ query?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson The field in the database is a datetimeoffset(7)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Yes I took that generated sql from the linq query and fired it in the sql studio but in the studio I get the last entry.

Comment: I think you're facing localization issue connected with different time zone on application server and DB server. Is that possible?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Just checked that but both servers do have the same time and timezone (UTC+01:00).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in august in the timezone the server is located in is not UTC+01:00 which it is right now, but UTC+02:00 because of the summer time. Thus the last entry did not take part in august for this timezone but on the 1st of september.